# aggregating matrix and cell array

Tags: matlab, aggregation

I am aggregating 3x3 matrix D to 2x2 (adding column/row 1 and 2 together).  Names for the rows and columns of matrix D are kept in 1x3 vector m. 
And I am looking for a way to aggregate vector M by removing one of elements so it has the size 2x1.

Given 3x3 matrix D:

```
D = 
 1 2 3
 4 5 6
 7 8 9
```

And 2x3 aggregation matrix S:

```
S = 
 1 1 0
 0 0 1
```

I aggregate D into 2x2 matrix by:

```
D = S*D*S' 

D = 
 12 15   
  9  9
```

And the names for the columns and rows are stored in 3x1 vector m.

```
m = 
 'A'   
 'B'
 'C'
```

I want to remove element 2 ('B') so the final output looks like this:

```
m = 
 'A'   
 'C'
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why the second and not the third? Removing an element can be done by `m(2)=[]`

Comment: The second because m(1) + m(2) but I only want to keep the name of m(1). Your solution would work but I need some way to know which indices I should pass i.e. how do I know it is 2 in m(2) ?

Comment: "The second because m(1) + m(2)" <- that sentence makes no sense.

Comment: You know which rows/column you add so then you also know what index to use in m.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you want to find the top left corners of blocks of a block-diagonal matrix and return their column indexes.

For example for the following matrix:

```
11100      10000
11100      00000   
00010  =>  00010
00010      00000
00001      00001
```

The result will be `[1 4 5]`.

```
S = [1 1 0
     0 0 1];
m = {'A';'B';'C'};
sz = size(S);
h = diff([zeros(sz(1),1),S],1,2)>0;
v = diff([zeros(1,sz(2));S],1,1)>0;
[~,idx]=find(h&v);
result = m(idx)
```